# Get friends attending to an event with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

For example there is an event in Facebook - I can get all attendees using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<event_id>/attending
```

**But I want to get only list of user's friends that age going to attend.**

And if i have big list of event attendees it will take a lot of time to filter only friends in this list. Imagine you have about 40 events and few hundreds of attendees at each of them. In order to use this data in mobile app or somewhere else I will need to recalculate this lists every hour/day and store it somewhere.

I know that there were some questions like this that were asked before - and the answer was to use FQL for it. But it seems that FQL in not available since 2016.

So how should I get list of user's friends that are going to visit specific events?

Comment: you can only get a list of friends who authorized your app too, so it would be impossible to match them. i would say it is not possible at all.

Comment: There is no way to filter event attendees this way. You will have to do it on your end. (One of the reasons they removed FQL was that the filtering capabilities it offered were bad for overall system performance.)

Comment: but facebook definitely have this feature because when I open event - I first see photos of my friends that are going to visit this event. How do they handle it?